# VS Code plugin that tells you how many times exports are imported?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to know how many times an export is used in order to help with cleaning up large codebases.

Example:

`export wtv = (...) => {...} // imported in 3 files`

Knowing that the export is used in 3 files and which are those files with something simple like a hover tooltip would greatly help.

Is there maybe also an alternative way to get a similar result?